# HTML / CSS / JS --> Syntax Error: Animated SignUp Form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I followed advice from this site on how to embed
the code that i found on how to recreate the
Animated Sign In Form … shown here:

https://youtu.be/5uANWpkuPww

I was hoping to modify it, so that one face of the
animated circle contained text inviting people to
subscribe to my mailing list … with the clickable
link causing the circle to rotate, allowing people
to then enter their name and email address.

In any case, I got the code from:

https://github.com/DaftCreation/Animated-Sign-In---Sign-Up-Form

and tried it out on w3schools.com

Here is the result:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G15FD7XT1JF6

If anybody will be kind enough to get it to work,
please save it on w3schools.com … and post the link / URL
here on stackoverflow.com

I am guessing that the guy that created it, may have left out
a character or two, when he cut and pasted it, which has
resulting in the code not working correctly ... and be sure to
let me know what was wrong with it, so that i can learn from this.

Thanks  : )

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Kindly put your code here in the question to make it easier to answer

Comment: asking someone to do your work for you has never been a socially acceptable ask. Welcome to stackoverflow though! If you need help with a specific issue regarding your code, please refine your question to describe that issue.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - i assumed that the code does not work correctly because a character was lost when it was cut and pasted. Thusly if somebody spots what is wrong with the syntax it will no doubt be quicker for them to add the missing character and save it ...then to post the link and tell me what was missing, rather than them having to type a longish explaination. So no, i did not assume that anybody will spend any time 'rewriting' code, as i am confident that it works like the YouTube Video shows albeit it just needs a missing character added / reinstalled  : )

Comment: @JamesJames https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine - the only real problem with is that you didn't wrap your jQuery in between `<script></script>` tags. Use the link below and you can see it working.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G15LTVZCBB4R

Also you need to make sure your jQuery link is valid (just copy and paste the one from my code - it is via Google CDN).

Comment: Tom O - Thank you for taking the time to look at it ... and supplying the answer [fixing it]. You are my hero.

Comment: Glad it helped!